# Is there a Graphics Mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I noticed there was a lot of discussion here about Dwarf Fortress, so I looked it up and downloaded it. I was surprised to find it was all in text.

Is there a graphics mode for this game?

I would like to check it out because I'm a fan of old games and all... but I'd at least like some graphics! Where can I find a newer version (if there is one?) that has graphics?

Comment: -1 for Blasphemy.

Comment: (He's joking)...

Comment: To be fair, graphics packs are a great way to get into a game like this, which is rediculously daunting in almost every way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no "graphics mode" for Dwarf Fortress. However, the game was designed to be easily modded, and that includes changing which tiles are displayed for the dwarves, monsters, most everything, really. There are several graphics packs floating around.

[Phoebus'](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=57557.0) graphics set is one popular option, and [Ironhand's](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=53180.0) graphics set is another.

If you're completely new to Dwarf Fortress, I'd suggest the [Lazy Newb Pack](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=59026.0), which contains both of those graphics sets, as well as a few other helpful utilities, such as Dwarf Therapist. (Though at the time of this answer, the Lazy Newb Pack has yet to be updated to the latest version of Dwarf Fortress, 31.18)

Comment: I had a similar feeling about the game, and I can confirm that "graphics" packs allowed me to play many hours comfortably. The graphical experience is decidedly old school, but it's not text. I will also recommend the Mike Mayday pack, as it looks nice and tends to keep updated versions, with downloads for DF + graphics pre-installed (for zero additional setup).

Comment: Also, if you do get into the game with graphics packs, try using the text mode again when you're comfortable with the gameplay. You may find it's not so bad after all.

Comment: Or when a new version is out and you don't want to wait for the graphics set to be properly updated!

Comment: Do any of the graphics packages for Dwarf Fortess work on Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. It's called [Stone Sense](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=43260.0). Well, it might be a stretch to claim it's fully graphical, but it will let you view the game in isometric 3d. So kind of?! Raven's answer is probably more practical, as unless you have a VERY boss machine, running DF and Stone Sense at the same time is probably going to eat up a fair bit resource wise.

Comment: Disclaimer: Stone Sense is not officially supported. It is a fan program that reads Dwarf fortress' memory. It is not dwarf fortress' graphics mode.  Dwarf fortress has no graphics mode.

Comment: I don't think Dwarf Therapist is officially supported either?!

Comment: No, it isn't.